# How to get all combinations of values in a 2D array with loops by taking one value from all row each time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

the 2D array I'm dealing with might has different length on each row, like:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ["orange", "poke"];
var c = ["melon", "table", 93, 71, "rock"];
var arrayA = [a, b, c];
```

And the I want to get all the combinations of values from array like this:

```
var result = [arrayA[0][0], arrayA[1][0], arrayA[2][0]];
//some operation with result
result = [arrayA[0][0], arrayA[1][0], arrayA[2][1]];
//some operation with result
result = [arrayA[0][0], arrayA[1][0], arrayA[2][2]];
//some operation with result
.
.
.
.
.
.
result = [arrayA[0][2], arrayA[1][1], arrayA[2][4]];
//some operation with result
```

Is this possible to achieve these with loops while dealing with **2D array with various length** of in the javascript? If not, is there other way to do this?Thx

Comment: You are looking for cartesian product
[Cartesian product of multiple arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303989/cartesian-product-of-multiple-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get each combination and do something with each one a nice way to handle this is use a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators). This avoids creating a potentially large list in memory while still being convenient to loop over each combination. For example:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var b = ["orange", "poke"];
var c = ["melon", "table", 93, 71, "rock"];
var arrayA = [a, b, c];

function* productGen(arr, cur = []){
  if (arr.length < 1) yield cur
  else {
    for (let item of arr[0]) {
      yield* productGen(arr.slice(1), [...cur, item])
    }
  }
}

for (let combo of productGen(arrayA)){
  // do something with combo
  console.log(combo)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rather inefficient solution that does not involve a generator (for platforms that do not support generator functions yet)

```
const combinations = arrayA.reduce((previous, current) => {

    if (current.length === 0)
        return previous;

    const accumulate = current.map(x => {

        if (previous.length === 0)
            return current;

        return previous.map(y => {
            return [x, y];
        });
    });

    // Flatten combinations
    return accumulate.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, ...x]);
});

combinations.forEach(combination => console.log(combination));
```